# How the fix localization warning on RVIZ?

Tags: python, ros, gazebo-simu, rviz

I am trying to create simple send way point to turtlebot3 on gazebo and R viz. I wrote  the code with python like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import actionlib
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
from math import radians, degrees
from actionlib_msgs.msg import *
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point




#this method will make the robot move to the goal location
def move_to_goal(xGoal,yGoal):

   #define a client for to send goal requests to the move_base server through a SimpleActionClient
   ac = actionlib.SimpleActionClient("move_base", MoveBaseAction)

   #wait for the action server to come up
   while(not ac.wait_for_server(rospy.Duration.from_sec(5.0))):
           rospy.loginfo("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up")

   goal = MoveBaseGoal()
   
   
   #set up the frame parameters
   goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "odom"
   goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

   # moving towards the goal*/

   goal.target_pose.pose.position =  Point(xGoal,yGoal,0)
   goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
   goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
   goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
   goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

   rospy.loginfo("Sending goal location ...")
   ac.send_goal(goal)

   ac.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration(60))

   if(ac.get_state() ==  GoalStatus.SUCCEEDED):
           rospy.loginfo("You have reached the destination")
           return True

   else:
           rospy.loginfo("The robot failed to reach the destination")
           return False

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       rospy.init_node('map_navigation', anonymous=False)
       x_goal = -3.027778387069702
       y_goal = 1.005319595336914
       print('start go to goal')
       move_to_goal(x_goal,y_goal)
       rospy.spin()
```

Then i run these commands:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch
roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:={PATH}
rosrun mapping_example navigation.py
```

I use UBUNTU 20.04 and my python version is 'Python 3.8.10' Also i use ROS Noetic.
Below, the images are the warnings:
[image: Warning Description]

[image: Initial pose setting]